# integrals of positive and negative parts for integrable function

Tags: integration

If $a>0$ and $\int\limits_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx < \infty$,
can we claim that $\int\limits_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\int\limits_{a}^{\infty}f^{+}(x)dx-\int\limits_{a}^{\infty}f^{-}(x)dx$
and what can we say about integrals of positive and negative parts?

Comment: The equality is true iff both parts are integrable and if you want to calculate a geometric area.

Comment: So basically, you cannot bypass the absolute integrability as an assumption for the equaility?